# Uploading image from react to laravel api

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm having trouble uploading files from react to a laravel api. I have a backend for uploading a post that has title,body and image. if their is an image it should save the url of the image and if not save a default value. i tested with postman and it worked correctly but when i'm trying to upload from my react front end, it saves noimage for every trial.

Laravel api

```
public function save(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            'title'=>'required',
            'body'=>'required',
            'user_id'=>'required'
        ]);
        $post = new Post();
            $post->title = $request->title;
            $post->body= $request->body;
            $post->user_id= auth()->user()->id;
            if($request->hasFile('image')){
                $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
                $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $fileExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'. time() .'.'.$fileExt;
                $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images',$fileNameToStore);
            }else{
                $fileNameToStore = "NoImage.jpg";
            }
            $post->image =$fileNameToStore;
            $post->save();

        return new PostResource($post);
    }
```

React code

```
    const [imgName,setImgName] = useState('Choose Image');
        const [postImg,setPostImg] = useState()
        const [postData,setPostData] = useState({
            title:'',
            body:''
        });
    
        const {title,body} = postData;
    
        const changeHandler = e =>{  
           setPostData({...postData,[e.target.name]:e.target.value});
        }
    
        const fileHandler = e=>{
            setImgName(e.target.files[0].name);
            setPostImg(e.target.files[0]);
            
        }
    
        const submitHandler = e =>{
            e.preventDefault();
            
            if(!title || !body){
                props.setMsg("You can't leave title or body field blank",'warning');
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    props.clearError()
                },3000)
            }else{
                const fd = new FormData();
                fd.append('image',postImg)
                const data = {
                    title:title,
                    body:body,
                    image:fd
                }
                
                props.onCreatePost(data);
                console.log(fd.get('image'));
                
            }
           
        }
```

I'm using redux to with react

`

```
export const createPost = (formData)=>{
    return (dispatch) =>{
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        const config ={
            headers:{
                'Authorization':`Bearer ${token}`,
                
            }, 
        }
        console.log('Sent Data: ',formData);
           axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts`,formData,config)
            .then(res=>{
                dispatch(addPost(res.data))
            }).catch(err=>{
                dispatch(postfailed(err.response))
            })        
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Please post code which uploads the image to your backend.

Comment: It's not clear when your code post the data to your backend. You have declared ```formdata``` but seems not used which ``props.onCreatePost(data);``` submit data object to a method whose definition is not available

Comment: `export const createPost = (formData)=>{
    return (dispatch) =>{
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        const config ={
            headers:{
                'Authorization':`Bearer ${token}`,
                
            }, 
        }
        console.log('Sent Data: ',formData);
           axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts`,formData,config)
            .then(res=>{
                dispatch(addPost(res.data))
            }).catch(err=>{
                dispatch(postfailed(err.response))
            })        
    }
}`

Comment: Please add this to your question so it's more readable.

Comment: I have done that, Thank you this is my first time of asking question here

Comment: try updating ```props.onCreatePost(data);``` to ```props.onCreatePost(fd);```

Comment: If i do that, the other fields {title,body} that i'm sending along won't be their

Comment: You need to add them in form data instead of making formdata part of the object.

Comment: I don't get what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your formdata to following

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('image',postImg)
fd.append('title', title)
fd.append('body',body)
props.onCreatePost(fd);
```

Then use header as explained by @gbalduzzi

Comment: Wow. it worked thank you very much, i'm really grateful

Answer (score 3):

You need to send the request as `multipart/form-data` if you need to include files in your post request:

```js
const config ={
    headers:{
        'Authorization':`Bearer ${token}`,
         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
     }, 
}
```

If you want to learn more about the subject I suggest you read this: [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)

---

Also, you must attach every field as formData, you can't create a javascript object with a formdata inside

Instead of:

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('image',postImg)
const data = {
   title:title,
   body:body,
   image:fd
}
                
props.onCreatePost(data);
```

Do:

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('image',postImg)
fd.append('title', title)
fd.append('body', body)             
props.onCreatePost(fd);
```

Comment: this method didnt work. i get an error that I'm trying to insert empty data in the database

Comment: I edited my answer, didn't see that you were not using the formData object